# Extend Array to conform to protocol if Element conforms to given protocol

Tags: ios, swift, protocols, protocol-extension

I'd like to do something like this, but can't get the syntax right or find anywhere on the web that gives the right way to write it:

```
protocol JSONDecodeable {
    static func withJSON(json: NSDictionary) -> Self?
}

protocol JSONCollectionElement: JSONDecodeable {
    static var key: String { get }
}

extension Array: JSONDecodeable where Element: JSONCollectionElement {
    static func withJSON(json: NSDictionary) -> Array? {
        var array: [Element]?
        if let elementJSON = json[Element.key] as? [NSDictionary] {
            array = [Element]()
            for dict in elementJSON {
                if let element = Element.withJSON(dict) {
                    array?.append(element)
                }
            }
        }
        return array
    }
}
```

So I want to conform `Array` to my protocol `JSONDecodeable` only when the elements of this array conform to `JSONCollectionElement`.

Is this possible? If so, what's the syntax?

Comment: Use generics something like Array<JSONCollectionElement>

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Swift 4.2**

In Swift 4.2 I was able to extend an array with the elements conforming to a protocol like this:

```
public extension Array where Element: CustomStringConvertible{
    public var customDescription: String{
        var description = ""
        for element in self{
            description += element.description + "\n"
        }

        return description
    }
}
```

Comment: Confirmed! Thank you! I had a quick look around for some info on this change in Swift 4.2, but couldn't find any. If anyone's got it please share!

Comment: And for optional array? Where Element must conform some protocol

Answer (score 5):

This isn't possible yet in Swift. You can see the same thing happen in the standard library: `Array` doesn't gain `Equatable` conformance when it's declared with `Equatable` elements.

Comment: @OrkhanAlikhanov still not possible. I am getting a `Extension of type 'Array' with constraints cannot have an inheritance clause` build time error from XCode.

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest using a wrapper. For instance

```
struct ArrayContainer<T: Decodable>: Container {
    let array: [T]
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I don't know if this is the best approach or if apple intended it to be used this way.  I used this once and it worked well for me:

Say you have the following protocol

```
protocol MyProtocol {
    var test: Bool { get }
}
```

You can do this for Arrays

```
extension Array: MyProtocol where Element: MyProtocol {
    var test: Bool {
        return self.allSatisfy({ $0.test })
    }
}
```

And this for Dictionaries

```
extension Dictionary: MyProtocol where Value: MyProtocol {
    var test: Bool {
        return self.values.allSatisfy({ $0.test })
    }
}
```